# Unable to access subfolder html file through <a> tag

Tags: html

I have a main folder with index.html file for my html app. I have written a code in index.html of main folder to access the file (index.html) present in the sub folder as follows,

```
<a href="subfolder/index.html">SubFile</a>
```

When i click on the above link, it is not navigating to the subfile and instead the link of main folder index.html file changes to mainfolder/index.html#!/subfolder/index.html

I even tried changing the name of subfolder file but no success. What could be the problem?

I also want to navigate back to the main folder index.html from subfolder as follow,

```
<a href="../index.html">Mainfile</a>
```

But it is also not working. How can I achieve this as well?

Edited:

The file my-app.js is creating the issue. The code of my-app.js is as follows,

```
    // Initialize your app
var myApp = new Framework7({
    animateNavBackIcon: true,
    // Enable templates auto precompilation
    precompileTemplates: true,
    // Enabled pages rendering using Template7
    swipeBackPage: false,
    swipeBackPageThreshold: 1,
    swipePanel: "left",
    swipePanelCloseOpposite: true,
    pushState: true,
    pushStateRoot: undefined,
    pushStateNoAnimation: false,
    pushStateSeparator: '#!/',
    template7Pages: true
});


// Export selectors engine
var $$ = Dom7;

// Add main View
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
    // Enable dynamic Navbar
    dynamicNavbar: false
});


$$(document).on('pageInit', function (e) {
        $(".swipebox").swipebox();


    $("#ContactForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    ajaxContact(form);
    return false;
    }
    });

    $('a.backbutton').click(function(){
        parent.history.back();
        return false;
    });


    $(".posts li").hide();  
    size_li = $(".posts li").size();
    x=4;
    $('.posts li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+1 <= size_li) ? x+1 : size_li;
        $('.posts li:lt('+x+')').show();
        if(x == size_li){
            $('#loadMore').hide();
            $('#showLess').show();
        }
    });


$("a.switcher").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var theid = $(this).attr("id");
    var theproducts = $("ul#photoslist");
    var classNames = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');


    if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        // if currently clicked button has the active class
        // then we do nothing!
        return false;
    } else {
        // otherwise we are clicking on the inactive button
        // and in the process of switching views!

        if(theid == "view13") {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $("#view11").removeClass("active");
            $("#view11").children("img").attr("src","images/switch_11.png");

            $("#view12").removeClass("active");
            $("#view12").children("img").attr("src","images/switch_12.png");

            var theimg = $(this).children("img");
            theimg.attr("src","images/switch_13_active.png");

            // remove the list class and change to grid
            theproducts.removeClass("photo_gallery_11");
            theproducts.removeClass("photo_gallery_12");
            theproducts.addClass("photo_gallery_13");

        }

        else if(theid == "view12") {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $("#view11").removeClass("active");
            $("#view11").children("img").attr("src","images/switch_11.png");

            $("#view13").removeClass("active");
            $("#view13").children("img").attr("src","images/switch_13.png");

            var theimg = $(this).children("img");
            theimg.attr("src","images/switch_12_active.png");

            // remove the list class and change to grid
            theproducts.removeClass("photo_gallery_11");
            theproducts.removeClass("photo_gallery_13");
            theproducts.addClass("photo_gallery_12");

        } 
        else if(theid == "view11") {
            $("#view12").removeClass("active");
            $("#view12").children("img").attr("src","images/switch_12.png");

            $("#view13").removeClass("active");
            $("#view13").children("img").attr("src","images/switch_13.png");

            var theimg = $(this).children("img");
            theimg.attr("src","images/switch_11_active.png");

            // remove the list class and change to grid
            theproducts.removeClass("photo_gallery_12");
            theproducts.removeClass("photo_gallery_13");
            theproducts.addClass("photo_gallery_11");

        } 

    }

}); 

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
   if(event.target.parentNode.className.indexOf('navbarpages') != -1 || event.target.className.indexOf('navbarpages') != -1 ) {
    event.preventDefault(); }
}, false);

// Add ScrollFix
var scrollingContent = document.getElementById("pages_maincontent");
new ScrollFix(scrollingContent);


var ScrollFix = function(elem) {
    // Variables to track inputs
    var startY = startTopScroll = deltaY = undefined,

    elem = elem || elem.querySelector(elem);

    // If there is no element, then do nothing  
    if(!elem)
        return;

    // Handle the start of interactions
    elem.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){
        startY = event.touches[0].pageY;
        startTopScroll = elem.scrollTop;

        if(startTopScroll <= 0)
            elem.scrollTop = 1;

        if(startTopScroll + elem.offsetHeight >= elem.scrollHeight)
            elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight - elem.offsetHeight - 1;
    }, false);
};

})
```

What shall i remove from it to solve my problem?

Comment: Is there any htaccess file in your root dir?

Comment: @Mitul, No! There is no htaccess file.

Comment: Why subfolder url is `mainfolder/index.html#!/subfolder/index.html`

Comment: Ya, thats what I don't understand. I am writing href="subfolder/index.html" but when i click on the link it changes to mainfolder/index#!/subfolder/index.html

Comment: Do you have `<base href>` tag declared on `<header>` ?

Comment: @gmo There is no <base href> tag

Comment: I see.. please update your question with more and relevant info, add appropriate tags with the language you're using, frameworks, external libraries ... And if you could (would be ideal) a working example to reproduce the issue (as content snippet, external jsfiddle ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#!/subfolder/index.html`

This make me feel that you are using a single page application framework/library, like Angular or something related. So maybe your problem is not in the html but in your javascript code.

Comment: Actually I had downloaded the html app. I am not sure of framework. How can I solve it then? I went through js folder. There are files like email.js, framework7.js, jquery.swipebox.js, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove all javascript and check it will work fine then revert all js one by one and test you will find the conflict javascript resolve that conflict. it will work fine.

Comment: I tried your answer. I came to know my-app.js is creating the problem. What do I need to remove from that file?